# Error - file not found when it is definitely there

Tags: c#, .net, win32exception

I am trying to run a process with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`, but am getting the following error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
```

I double checked the path, and even copied the string to a `cmd` window, where it ran just fine. What could be the problem?

I am using Win7 64 bit, the program I am trying to run was compiled with mingw64-x64, and I am compiling for .NET 2.0

**EDIT**
While trying to do the suggested

```
if (File.Exists(Your EXE)) {
}
```

I found that removing the flags from the command string solved the problem (I didn't think this was an issue and so didn't mention it before)

How do I run commands with parameters?

Comment: is it an absolute or relative path?

Comment: Could you provide more in your code example?

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a permissions issue? Is it running from a network drive? Is the application running under a different user account to the one you checked it with? Is the file in the root of the C drive or somewhere "protected" like the windows directory; because UAC might get in the way as you're on windows 7.

Comment: Try posting your code which is not working, then you will get more help.

Comment: Is your .NET build set to 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arguments use [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx). Or overload with ProcessStartInfo.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 folder redirection could be the issue.

Basically sometimes when you try to access "C:\program files" it will redirect you to something like "C:\users\username\program files"

I'm looking up some resources for you. I'll let you know when I find something that explains it better than I can.

**EDIT:**

I find that commands with parameters are a *pain* in the butt to get working correctly. I usually just resort to writing a batch file and then have C# run that.

Comment: [Environment.SpecialFolder enum?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

Comment: On 64bit system Windows redirects some folders for 32 bit processes. It is called WOW64. (Windows on Windows)

Comment: I would hate to have you spend time looking for nothing. Please see my edit.

Comment: @baruch - Well I do have a recommendation for your subsequent question.

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement like:

```
if (File.Exists(Your EXE))
{
    // Start the process
}
```

Otherwise you can not make sure the Path used is the right one.

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4358190/395659) too, maby it helps

Comment: Race condition. Filesystem is a shared resource. Your file may exist for call to File.Exists() and be removed before next call. Besides this did not answer the question at all.

Comment: The question is different, it's not about avoiding exceptions, it's about why the process cannot start even if the executable file IS there

Comment: TheAssumption that the file is at the right palce is something you have to gaurantee, when i read the exception beeing thrown i trust the system that the file isnt in the place the PO assumes it is, therefor such an if statement can spare u lots of time if you notice that the file doesnt exist at the place u thing it does, if file exists then you can go further and check the issue why isnt it getting started, but i dont really think this would be the case.

Comment: @Kugel i check allways fiel for existence before i access them, thats why the function is there, i never had any problem with that, but shoudl this happen then you will get a suitable message that the file is beeign usedb y another process. as saied this shouldnt happen as File.Exists shouldnt actually block the file after methode was left.

Comment: The problem revealed to be a wrong usage of Process.Start() API, not related to the existence of the file.

Comment: Still the PO found the reason whle trying to set File.Exists :) admit it!

Answer (score 0):

Use the ProcessStartInfo class and set values to the Arguments property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx